# Why are my div boxes ignoring my css code?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, html

Firstly, I would like to say that I have tested if my link to my .css works, the background is made into a black color.

This is a ASP.NET Mvc test application which I am making, and I am having difficulty positioning some of my elements which are nested in div boxes. I have come to the conclusion that my div boxes nested within the topmostheader box is ignoring my .css code.

Here is my entire css file, called custom1.css

```
#topmostheader
{               
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(0, 0, 0);
    height: 90px;
    text-align: center;
}

#topmostheader.inner
{
    width: 1280px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: Red;
}

#topmostheader.app-name
{
    font-size: 14px;
    float: left;
    line-height: 90px;
    color: rgb(119,119,119);
    margin: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
}
#topmostheader.xxx-logo
{
    margin: 0px;
    height: 90px;
    float: right;
}
```

and here is my div box layout.

```
<div id="topmostheader">
    <div class="inner" >
        <div class="app-name">
            Lunch Application
        </div>
        <div class="xxx-logo">
            <img src="/content/xxx/logo.png" alt="xxx logo"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The desired result is not produced: the app-name, inner and acceleration logo divboxes are all dead-center in the screen, where the app-name must be in the left side, and the logo in the right.

I have tested the following code (Which produced the desired result, in an undesired manner - I may reuse this code multiple times which are in the .css file)

```
<div id="topmostheader">
    <div class="inner" >
        <div class="app-name" style="float:left">
            Lunch Application
        </div>
        <div class="xxx-logo" style="float:right">
            <img src="/content/xxx/logo.png" alt="xxx logo"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong? Why are my div boxes not "floating" when I use the .css file?

Comment: 3 right answers :O who to give the check to :|

Comment: I’m pretty sure by custom it goes to the answerer with the longest display name.

Comment: lol. At least I had a good laugh now.

Comment: But I do understand your explanation the most

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You’re missing a space between your ID selectors and your class selectors.

`#topmostheader.inner` means “select the element with an id of `topmostheader` and a class of `inner`”.

You want `#topmostheader .inner`, which means “select elements with a class of `inner` that are descendants of the element with an id of `topmostheader`“

Answer (score 6):

To target the correct divs you need a space between the id and class name in your CSS rules: (e.g. change `#topmostheader.app-name` to `#topmostheader .app-name`)

Answer (score 5):

you need to put a space between the id `#topmostheader` and the class e.g. `.acceleration-logo` otherwise the browser assumes you are applying style to div with id `#topmostheader` and class `.acceleration-logo` not a child of class `.acceleration-logo` with parent of `#topmostheader`